# HTML/CSS URL path

Tags: html, css, url

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have tried to look for solutions and haven't found one so I came here. This is my HTML Folder
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzlU9.png

SITE/Fonts/school.ttf

SITE/Pictures/praycat.jpg

SITE/index.html

SITE/main.css

This is my CSS File

```
html { 
  background: url('Pictures/praycat.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url('Fonts/school.ttf');
}
```

When I open my index, everything works(the images are accessed and the fonts.
But, when I visit my site, the images and the fonts are missing. What am I doing wrong?

HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--Let's load jQuery-->
<script>

function GameDetails( servername, serverurl, mapname, maxplayers, steamid, gamemode )
{
$("#mapName").text(mapname);
$("#gameMode").text(gamemode);
$("#serverName").text(servername);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<audio autoplay loop>
    <source src="somesoundfile.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
</body>
<body>
<div>
<p class="small">
    <h1 id="titlePg"><b>You're on your way to <span id="serverName">unknown</span></b></h1>
</div>
</p>
We're currently playing <span id="mapName">unknown</span> on <span id="gameMode">unknown</span>
</body>

</html>
```

CONSOLE:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK5ji.png

Comment: are you linking the images and fonts file correctly

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: just open your console in the browser and check what is the error message it shows, try to fix that error

Comment: Change `html` to `body`

Comment: Well, I am using microsoft edge browser to open the file, and i visit the website using firefox & chrome.

Comment: also how do I open console?

Answer (score 1):

Try using ../ before the URL as it represents your root:

```
body{ 
  background: url('../Pictures/praycat.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url('../Fonts/school.ttf');
}
```

Comment: also does it help that i'm using dropbox to host the site?

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to change the HTML tag to Body. Then you need to setup the root directory "..\wherever your files are stored\filename" As with the last posts we have all seem to gravitate to the same answer. Let us know if this works. If not can you post your html code too so that we can see the code and help there too. Best of luck.

***UPDATED*** Here is your code that I was able to fix in the CSS:

```
background-image: url("\\main Directory\User\Desktop\Pictures/praycat.png");
```

You need to add "-image" after the background and use double quotes in the directory for the picture. I also took out the verbiage after the image source. This is your old code on top and the code that I used underneath:

```css
background: url('Pictures/praycat.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;

background-image: url("\\main Directory\User\Desktop\Pictures/praycat.png");
This is found under html or body in CSS.
```

You will need to change the directory to point directly to the picture. You can usually right click the image, click properties, and it should be right there for you as to the location of its storage.

Comment: how would I set up a root directory? changing the tag did not work.

Comment: This is the root directory that I have setup for pictures to be displayed on my site that I have used at work in the past. {<img src="\\Main Storage \Sub directory\Bruce's Training Class\WebPages\Pictures\defeat.jpg">}. The root directory is where all of your informaiton is stored and related to from the call proceedure on the webpage.

Comment: If you have all of your website and files stored on you computer the html will look first for the files in the same folder as itself. If they are not in the same folder then you will get the "x" img for the photo. This is where you point to the folder that has the file you want and then the file name at the end. much the same as I have posted above. The only difference is that I posted the full directory of where my pictures were and the file that I wanted to have displayed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I noticed is you have two head tags

```
<head>
<head>
CSS link
</head>
</head>
```

Try getting rid of one of them

```
<head>
CSS link
</head>
```

Comment: that did not work. could you figure out what is wrong by looking at console? i.stack.imgur.com/yK5ji.png

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try starting your path with `"../"` may be that would help